# What is the simplest way to display Instagram follower count

Tags: api, instagram

I am using WordPress and trying to figure out the simplest way to display the amount of Instagram followers a user has.

Whilst searching I have found a few Instagram PHP wrapper scripts that seem a little overkill for what I am trying to display.

From reading through the Stackoverflow posts I came across a post that listed this code:

```
$userinfo = wp_remote_get("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3955450?access_token=f0d225aa955c4bd9ae563f87f831efab");
$userinfo = json_decode($userinfo);

$followers = $userinfo['data']['counts']['followed_by'];

echo "Folled by: " . $followers . " people";
```

This is a simple and perfect script HOWEVER it does not return any data.

I have setup a client on the Instagram Developer site however I cannot get the above script to display any data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3955450?access_token=f0d225aa955c4bd9ae563f87f831efab");
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->data[0]->id;
```

Comment: the "t" in **file_get_contents** is missing ;)